# Should I ng eject webpack config?

Tags: angular, webpack

**What are the advantages and disadvantages of ng ejected webpack configuration in an Angular 4 project ?**

---

Here is the case which made me think of this:

I have a Shared project which is refered by two other projects.

I use the PrimeNG library and when a PrimeNG component is refered not directly but from the shared project, angular-cli throws thousands of warnings like this:

```
WARNING in ../MyProjectName/~/primeng/components/orderlist/orderlist.js
Cannot find source file '../../src/app/components/orderlist/orderlist.ts': 

    Error: C               an't resolve '../../src/app/components/orderlist/orderlist.ts' in 
'...MyProjectName\node_modules\primeng\components\orderlist'
         @ ../MyProjectName/~/primeng/primeng.js 50:9-52
```

because of a hardcoded path in all *.map files in primeng library, like this one:

```
"sources":["../../src/app/components/datatable/datatable.ts"]
```

When ejected, the webpack.config file could be set to exclude PrimeNG sourcemaps loading and these warnings disappear.

---

**But are these warnings a big enough reason to eject the configuration ? What are the other advantages I could benefit from when ejecting and are there any drawbacks or problems I could get stuck with?**

Comment: Did you see this thread? https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6302

Comment: see this https://medium.com/@s2dent/from-angular-cli-to-webpack-2-and-other-production-solutions-with-examples-f127abe06842

Comment: More configurable or more flexible does not sound like a serious detailed argument.

Comment: @IvelinMatev but yeah, that is the argument unfortunately. Unless you don't need any different config, stay with cli default configs, they will keep that up to date, you won't have to worry about anything.

Comment: @Matheus Silva Be more specific please. What type of configs could be done with ejected webpack, that can not be done with the wrapped config in cli. Give me some examples, please.